# Java/Spring catching Exceptions/Logging and Update status

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-transactions

Lets say that from a spring service, i want to invoke through a client an external system, if that invocation fails (throws unchecked exception) i want to log it, update order status in DB and rethrow the exception for the transaction to be rollbacked...

I know that below sample code is considered to be an anti-pattern but i cannot think of something better to achieve this...any comments pls?

```
public class Service {

@Autowired(required = true)
private Client client;

@Autowired(required = true)
private DAO d;

@Transactional
@Override
public void register(String id) {

     try{
      client.invoke(id);//throws Client unchecked exception
     }
     catch (ClientException e){
         LOG.error (e);
         d.updateStatus(id,"failed");
         throw e;
      }
 }
}
```

Comment: it should be fine. But in catch you should write : `throw new ClientException(e)` .

Comment: why ? wrapping the exception has only interest if the wrapper type is different than the original one. He mades it the good way

Comment: yes, throw e; will just rethrow my exception...but is there any better way of achieving this?

Comment: @boom123: i think you have done the best way to achieve this.

Comment: I don't think the both status update and transaction rollback can be done at the same transaction

Comment: In your case I don't think the status will get updated since you are throwing an RuntimeException(ClientException)

Comment: that also won't work, you need to move the `d.updateStatus(id,"failed")` to a different service class with `PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW`

Comment: I tried what you said and i get The transaction is no longer active - status: 'Marked rollback. [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.AppSetRollbackOnlyException: setRollbackOnly called on transaction]'. No further JDBC access is allowed within this transaction.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: The transaction is no longer active - status: 'Marked rollback. [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.AppSetRollbackOnlyException: setRollbackOnly called on transaction]'.

Answer (score 0):

If you throw the Exception just to make the transaction rollback you should better consume it and call setRollbackOnly

```
  TransactionInterceptor.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
```

Comment: Yes I am aware of this, but in Spring Documentantion is again considered a BAD practice...

Comment: maybe you can find your solution here so http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?79852-Programmatically-rollback-the-CURRENT-transaction

Comment: Anyway In JPA the right way here will be to use `EJBContext.setRollbackOnly()`. I'am not however very aware of spring practice but i don't see why it should be different